# How do I control when code executes in the on_draw event of gktmm3-Gtk::DrawingArea

Tags: c++, gtk, cairo, gtkmm

I am using C++11 with GNU tool chain with gtkmm3, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit.
I have been experimenting with some of the examples for gtkmm3 in [**Programming with gtkmm 3**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/).

Based on [**17.2.1.Example**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html.en#cairo-example-lines) there, I inherited from `Gtk::DrawingArea` (`MyDrawingArea` here) and overrode the `on_draw()` event handler as follows:

***MyDrawingArea.hpp***

```
...

protected:

  bool on_draw ( const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr ) override;
```

***MyDrawingArea.cpp*** *(quick and dirty, just for concept demo)*

```
double y{ 10 };
double x{ 10 };

bool MyDrawingArea::on_draw( const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr )
{
        this->get_window( )->freeze_updates( );
        cr->set_line_width( 3.0 );
        cr->set_source_rgb( 1, 0, 0 );
        cr->move_to( x, y );
        cr->line_to( x * 2, y * 2 );
        cr->stroke( );
        this->get_window( )->thaw_updates( );
        x += 50;
        y += 50;
        return true;
 }
```

This code draws a single diagonal line. I want its position to change when I call`MyDrawingArea.queue_draw()` through an event handler in my application. This works:

Event 1:
[image]
Event 2:
[image]

My problem is that, obviously, the `on_draw()` event handler fires every time the window is repainted. Simply moving the application's main window (which contains `MyDrawingArea`) causes `on_draw()` to fire and the line is rendered in a new position.

How do I control when the code in my `on_draw()` event will run, so that the line is rendered anew only when I call `MyDrawingArea.queue_draw()` in my application code, but is preserved in its previous state at other times? (I don't **think** I'm asking about how to prevent `on_draw()` from firing, but perhaps that's what has to happen?)

Simply setting a flag notifying that my event has made the call and only then running my code to render the line raises other problems, because when the flag is not set, I lose everything that was previously rendered.

This seems to be an impossible situation: Either the line is redrawn in a new position for every `on_draw()` event, or erased completely if I use a flag to invoke my drawing logic, and `on_draw()` fires when that flag isn't set.

How should I manage this? Do I need logic to manage two different `on_draw()` options: If the app makes the call, render the new version of the line, if not, repaint the old version? This gets complicated - I'm thinking I'm missing something. Is there a different event I should be using? Is the some way I can obtain from `Cairo::Context` information about who called `On_draw()`, etc that would help me negotiate this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by writing a little state machine that controls how the `on_draw()` event behaves:

**Enum representing different signal states when on `on_draw()` fires:**

```
enum class Draw_Signals
{
    DS_RedrawSignal, DS_HoldSignal, DS_ClearSignal, DS_End
};

DS_RedrawSignal
```

Means redraw with new additions/changes as per the most recent application activity.

```
DS_HoldSignal
```

Means maintain the current graphics state but do nothing new.

```
DS_ClearSignal
```

Means clear the drawing area entirely and start over.

**The `MyDrawingArea` class has a member:**

`Draw_Signals mDSignal { Draw_Signals::DS_HoldSignal };`

This value is set by methods that trigger`on_draw()` from my application with a "setter" method.

**Without going into all the details, my `MyDrawingArea::on_draw()` now looks something like this:**

```
bool MyDrawingArea::on_draw( const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr )
    {

        get_window( )->freeze_updates( );

        switch ( mDSignal )
          {
            case Draw_Signals::DS_RedrawSignal:
              {
                DrawNewLine( cr );//draws new line and caches it for use when RedrawOldLine() is called.
                break;
              }

            case Draw_Signals::DS_HoldSignal:
              {
                RedrawOldLine( cr );
                break;
              }

            case Draw_Signals::DS_ClearSignal:
              {
                clearDrawArea( );
              }

          }

        get_window( )->thaw_updates( );

        mDSignal = Draw_Signals::DS_HoldSignal;

        return true;

    }
```

**They key here** is that the default state is always `Draw_Signals::DS_HoldSignal,` which simply redraws the previous content, and new drawing only occurs when explicitly signaled otherwise from the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to call your Gtk.DrawingArea on/off with a toggle button, just ask if toggle button is active or not than redraw the area.

```
<!------ language python ------>
def on_draw (self, widget):
    # your cairo draw here
    ......
    ......
    if toggle_button.get_active () is True: #toggle to show DrawingArea
        x+=50
        y+=50
    # other than that it simply sits there doing nothing
```

Now, about disconnect "draw" signal.. Put the last rendering copy of cr somewhere in buffer, and when you ready to fire it again, connect again but this time do not get the cairo *cr from "draw" signal param. Use the copy

Comment: _Put the last rendering copy of cr somewhere in buffer_ - I was hacking around with this and realized maybe that's what I have to do - see the edit I just posted : _Do I need logic..._ it includes exactly the option you suggest. I would do it by holding the old line parameters in a container somewhere. The actual app is more complicated and needs more parameters than I mentioned here, but it is doable. But there should be an easier way... If nobody comes up with anything better, you'll get the points.

Comment: glad to be a help, good luck with your project. if there is an easier way, and you find it, let me know

Comment: _just ask if toggle button is active_ - the button is not in scope for the class that handles the rendering. It has to be state information that's set in the rendering class, or a parameter in a function call into that class - something that can be set in central function in a controller class that's visible and callable to all potentially relevant front end members. It's not a good idea to bind your rendering logic to a specific component in your front end: **Tight coupling.**